# efficient, but still precise, multiple of exponent

Tags: scala, numerical-methods, exp

I need to compute efficiently an array of something like `f(i,a) = exp(-0.5 * (i-1) * i * a)` for all `i in (0..n)`, with `n` up to 20.000 and `a` a positive value very close to 0.

To avoid computing `exp` n times, I used an incremental approach such as (writing in scala):

```
def fInc(n: Int, a: Double)
  val expA = Math.exp(-a)
  var u = 1.0
  var v = 1.0

  var i = 1
  while(i < n){
    u *= expA
    v *= u // in practice I store that value in an array, for all i
    i += 1
  }
}

// reference by calling exp directly
def fRef(n: Int, a: Double) = Math.exp(-0.5 * (i-1) * i * a)
```

This is mathematically correct, but then the difference with direct exp computation is too big. Here are some results:

```
  n     a            v                Math.exp               diff
1000  1E-6   0.6068340008761639  0.6068340008714599  4.704014955336788E-12
1000  1E-9   0.9995006247427483  0.9995006247293567  1.3391510123028638E-11
1000  1E-12  0.9999995005111699  0.9999995005001248  1.1045164782785832E-11
1000  1E-15  0.9999999995008992  0.9999999995005     3.992361996552063E-13
10000 1E-6   1.938417748402E-22  1.938417746809E-22  1.5929953847004499E-31
10000 1E-9   0.9512341819777599  0.9512341806597269  1.3180330160622589E-9
10000 1E-12  0.9999500073554776  0.9999500062497292  1.1057483817467073E-9
10000 1E-15  0.9999999500449599  0.9999999500050013  3.995859199079632E-11
```

As you can see, for some values,the difference goes up to 1e-9, while I can accept maybe 1e-13

So question:

- Is there a way to get a better approximate with an algorithm that is still much more efficient than calling exp on all `i`?

Notes:

1. I use apache FastMath exp, which gives almost the same results as standard java exp.
2. The actual algorith is more complex, with other such incremental exp (not quadratic though)

Comment: Code reviews belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ And you might want to drop the #java tag.

Comment: I'm  not asking for a code review. I'm speaking about efficient numerical method. call exp n time (slow) vs product of exp (fast but not precise enough). The actual code is not important, I simply give it to explain my problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution I found:

The error being incremented (kind of) linearly with each multiplication by the "unitary exp(a)". We can think of the error as a function similar to `err(i) ~= i*i*err0` for some err0. The point is that the error of v is quadratic w.r.t i.

The best I found is:

1. reset the v to the correct value at some chosen frequency (each `k` iteration)
2. improve  the correctness of u each k iteration, using incremental exp computation

.

```
val k = 100
val expA = Math.exp(-a)
val expAk = Math.exp(-k*a)
var u = 1.0
var uk = 1.0
var v = 1.0

var i = 1
while(i < n){
  if(i%k==0){
    uk *= expAk
    u = uk
    v = Math.exp(- 0.5*(i+1)*i * a)
  } else{
    u *= expA
    v *= u
  }
  i += 1
}
```

This method  require n / k + 2 call to exp, not quite satifying but the best I have for now. It can probably be improved by choosing the best frequency parameter k.